# A system of linear PDEs with boundary conditions

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations, integrable-systems

I'm researching on discrete/semi-discrete/smooth differential geometry. Recently, I could simplify one of my geometric problems (in the smooth scenario) into the solutions of a system of linear PDEs that is

$$ 
e_v = L_u\,g,\quad\quad\quad g_u = L_v\,e
$$

where $L = \ln(\tan{(\frac{\omega}{2})})$ and $e(u,v),g(u,v),\omega(u,v): [0,a]\times [0,b] \subset \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are smooth functions on $(0,a)\times (0,b)$. Furthermore, I have the functions $e(u,0)$ and $g(0,v)$ and $\omega(u,v)$ as well.
I would like to show that the system has a solution for $e(u,v)$ and $g(u,v)$.
Unfortunately, my knowledge of PDEs is very limited but just from observing the counterpart of the above system in discrete and semi-discrete scenarios I have this kind of feeling that there should be a solution for the above system (with the boundaries that I mentioned).

Can someone clarify how I can prove that there exists a unique solution to the above system. I would very much appreciate if you can also go to details, describing non-characteristic curves and explaining why $e(u,0)$ and $g(0,v)$ are actually enough as boundary conditions (if they are). I think I also have to assume $e(u,v)$ and $g(u,v)$ are analytic functions. Is there any way to avoid this?

Please let me know if you need more details so that I can edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Let me rewrite the system as $E := e_v - L_u g = 0$, $G := g_u - L_v e = 0$. $L$ is taken to already be known. Some elementary calculations show that $$ P := e_{uv} - L_u L_v e - L_{uv} g = 0, \quad Q := g_{uv} - L_u L_v g - L_{uv} e = 0$$ is a differential consequence/integrability condition of the original system (exercise!). Some more elementary calculations show that the following identity holds
$$\tag{$*$}\label{eq:star}
  E_{uv} - L_u L_v E + L_{vv} G = P_v - L_v Q , \quad
  G_{uv} - L_u L_v G + L_{uu} E = Q_u - L_u P .
$$
These relations show that the original $(E,G)$-system can be recast as a constraint imposed on an evolution system (the $(P,Q)$-system consists of coupled [wave equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Algebraic_approach) in null coordinates $(u,v)$). The identity \eqref{eq:star} expresses the compatibility of the $(E,G)=0$ constraint with with evolution under the $(P,Q)$-system:

The left-hand sides of \eqref{eq:star} are themselves a system of coupled wave equations. If we specify initial $(e,g)$-data on $[0,a)\times 0$ and $0 \times [0,b)$ for the $(P,Q)$-system, it uniquely fixes the solutions inside $[0,a]\times[0,b]$, which moreover make the right-hand sides of \eqref{eq:star} zero. If in addition the initial $(e,g)$-data satisfy the $(E,G)=0$ constraint in the sense of giving vanishing initial data for \eqref{eq:star}, now interpreted as a homogeneous system of coupled wave equations, then uniquely evolving $(E,G)$ with \eqref{eq:star} from zero initial data forces $(E,G)=0$ throughout $[0,a]\times[0,b]$, which is what you wanted to conclude.

The existence and regularity of the solutions is handled by the standard well-posedness theory of the 2d wave equation (simply extended to coupled pairs of wave equations), so analyticity of the initial data/solutions is not necessary. The only thing missing from the OP's formulation of the initial value problem is requiring that the intial $(e,g)$-data satisfies the $(E,G)$-system on the initial data surface in the sense of giving vanishing initial data to the left-hand sides of \eqref{eq:star} (otherwise the solution will just not exist).

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer. You mentioned "wave equation". Isn't it like this that in a wave equation the two derivatives are related by a constant? I fail to see the resemblance here. would please explain about this part. I would also appreciate if you give a hint about the "null coordinate".

Comment: @ArvinRasoulzadeh Follow the precise link to Wikipedia to see the details of d'Alembert's solution to the wave equation. The equations above only differ by terms of lower (differential) order, which doesn't affect the well-posedness theory.